# Adding an Index degraded execution time

Tags: performance, oracle, oracle10g

I have a table like this:

```
myTable (id, group_id, run_date, table2_id, description)
```

I also have a index like this:

```
index myTable_grp_i on myTable (group_id)
```

I used to run a query like this:

```
select * from myTable t where t.group_id=3 and t.run_date='20120512';
```

and it worked fine and everyone was happy.
Until I added another index:

```
index myTable_tab2_i on myTable (table2_id)
```

My life became miserable... it's taking almost as 5 times longer to run !!!
execution plan looks the same (with or without the new index):

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name               | Rows  | Bytes | Cost
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |                    |     1 |   220 | 17019
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| MYTABLE            |     1 |   220 | 17019
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | MYTABLE_GRP_I      | 17056 |       |    61
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   1 - filter("T"."RUN_DATE"='20120512')
   2 - access("T"."GROUP_ID"=3)
```

I have almost no hair left on my head, why should another index which is not used, on a column which is not in the where clause make a difference ...

---

I will update the things I checked:
a. I removed the new index and it run faster
b. I added the new index in 2 more different environments and the same thing happen
c. I changed MYTABLE_GRP_I to be on columns run_date and group_id - this made it run fast as a lightning !!

But still why does it happen ?

Comment: I don't think it has to do anything with your problem, but is `RUN_DATE` of type `varchar2` ?? if so, this is a bad practice ...

Comment: Are the table and index statistics up-to-date? Can you just drop the second index? Is it needed for other queries?

Comment: What makes you believe that adding the second index created a performance problem rather than coincidentally being something that changed at about the time that your performance problems started?  Did you re-gather statistics on the table after adding the index?  Are you sure the actual query plan hasn't changed?  I would second A.B.Cade's comment that if `RUN_DATE` is a `VARCHAR2`, that's a bad practice.  And, for this query, you'd be better off with a composite index on `group_id` and `run_date`.

Comment: @SzilardBarany, Thanks for your response. Yes I checked the LAST_ANALYZE in user_tables, and used dbms_stats.gather_table_stats

Comment: Justin has a point here: do you have a baseline plan from before the changes for comparison?

Comment: I updated my question. I don't have a plan from before the change but it looks the same after removing the new index

Comment: To answer your question on why does it happen: Oracle's decisions on what to use and what not are mysteries to us, mortal people. Jonathan Lewis wrote a whole book on how he thinks the optimizer works. Fascinating work, like a detective book.

Comment: But can it be different from the execution plan ?

Comment: Can you [trace](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL_Trace) both versions to see what each is really doing?

Comment: Are there any other indexes on this table besides MYTABLE_GRP_I and MYTABLE_TAB2_I?

Comment: @BobJarvis, there is the another index on `id` column (which is the PK) but this index has always been there

Comment: @AlexPoole, I've traced it but I'm afraid that I found nothing... It works as expected (it's using the right index). Apparently with this index it works slow. I have no idea how come it used to run fast...

Comment: @Bassal - the plan shows what was expected to happen, the trace shows what really happened, particularly the real stats for rows, buffer hits, disk access etc. It sounds like you're *maybe* seeing some effect from buffer issues but not enough data to tell. For example, with the index, if you run the query twice, is the second faster?

Comment: @AlexPoole, Thanks for your response. Yes it is running faster. I can't make this run fast again (even after reoving the 2nd index) only if I gather stats it works fast but only for a short time...